# Linear Algebra: Is my proof of equivalence of cosets of $\mathsf W$ containing $v$ okay?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question is from exercise 31.b, Chapter 1, section 3 of *Linear Algebra 4th ed.* by Friedberg, Insel, Spence.

> Let $\mathsf W$ be a subspace of a vector space $\mathsf V$ over a field $F$. For any $v \in \mathsf V$ the set $\{v\} + \mathsf W = \{v + w: w \in \mathsf W\}$ is called the **coset** of $\mathsf W$ **containing** $v$. It is customary to denote this coset by $v + \mathsf W$ rather than $\{v\} + \mathsf W$.
>
>
> (b) Prove that $v_1 + \mathsf W = v_2 + \mathsf W$ if and only if $v_1 - v_2 \in \mathsf W$.

I understand and have proved going the one way, I just want to know if my proof of going the other way, that is: if $v_1 - v_2 \in \mathsf W$, then $v_1 + \mathsf W = v_2 + \mathsf W$ is correct. Here it is:

Assume that $v_1 - v_2 \in \mathsf W$, then $v_1 - v_2 = w \in \mathsf W$

$\implies$ $v_1 = v_2 + w$

$\implies v_1 \in v_2 + \mathsf W$.

Now, since $v_1 + \mathsf W = \{v_1 + w': w' \in \mathsf W\}$, then an element of $v_1 + \mathsf W$ is equal to $v_1 + w' = (v_2 + w) + w' = v_2 + (w + w')$, and $w + w' \in \mathsf W$ since $\mathsf W$ is a subspace, and so an element of $v_1 + \mathsf W$ is also an element of $v_2 + \mathsf W$ and so $v_1 + \mathsf W = v_2 + \mathsf W$.


Thank you for the help!

Comment: It is perfect except you only prove $\subseteq$ this side. But by symmetry, the other side followed.